# Classic asp large file download

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic ASP web site that needs to allow users to download a large file (CSV, 20 mb). The file is stored outside of the www root folder. I found some code examples on Stackoverflow and other web sites that send the file in chunks but can not get it to work. Both IE and chrome give an error "This webpage is not found".

Here is the entire code that I have for the asp file. What am I doing wrong?

```vb
<%@ LANGUAGE=VBScript %>

<%
s_getFile "D:\Data\Dev", "laser2.csv", "laser2"

Sub s_getFile(sPath, sfilename, sBaseName)

Response.Buffer = False 
Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000 

Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & sfilename 

Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 

adoStream.Open() 
adoStream.Type = 1 
adoStream.LoadFromFile(sPath & "\" & sBaseName) 

iSz = adoStream.Size 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", iSz' may be required

chunk = 2048 
For i = 1 To iSz \ chunk 
    If Not Response.IsClientConnected Then Exit For 
    Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read(chunk) 
Next 

If iSz Mod chunk > 0 Then 
    If Response.IsClientConnected Then 
        Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read(iSz Mod chunk) 
    End If 
End If 

adoStream.Close 
Set adoStream = Nothing 

Response.End 
End Sub 

%>
```

Comment: Could you provide some information about your environment, OS, IIS version etc)?

Answer (score 4):

When I tried removing the following line, it works.

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", iSz
```

Otherwise, I got "this webpage is not available" error (IIS not responding). I'm trying this on IIS 7.5 on Windows 7.  Using Fiddler, I see that IIS adds the "Content-Length" header automatically, so you don't have to.

Here is a link to [another user experiencing the same thing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.inetserver.iis/And_FaovAU4).

If the above doesn't work, **you need to check whether the file really exists**.  From your code above the file should be at `d:\data\dev\laser2` (no csv extension!).  I tested using a wrong file name, and I got a "This webpage is not found" error.  Digging deeper with Fiddler, I see the error is thrown by the ADODB.Stream component: File could not be opened.

Answer (score -1):

I tested many scripts but it didn't work, So I used this very simple trick and it Worked Good !

```
<% 
strFile="MyBigFile.zip"

strURL="https://"&Request.ServerVariables("server_name")&"/MyDownloadFolder"

response.redirect ""&strURL&"/"&strFile&""
%>
```